# How to push in 'class instance' or 'this' into a 'Function' method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am trying to put the user defined logic (Javascript) in frontend and my backend function execute it with 'Function' method (as below)

```
let cmdResult = Function('"use strict"; let _AW_DAY_SUMMARY_=' + JSON.stringify(_AW_DAY_SUMMARY_) + ';' + sUserDefinedCmd)()
...

this.alicia.dump();  // run the code correctly if hardcoded in script. But hit error below when defined by user frontpage
```

The user defined logic work correctly, and i was able to push in object with tons of values with JSON.stringify method. But i have a challenge as i have loaded quite a number of classes

```
constructor(
    private alicia: AliciaService,
    private benny: BennyService,
    private cass: CassService,
) { }
```

How could the user defined logic to allow call like this.alicia.dump();
Whenever i use it in my user defined logic, it complained

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'alicia' of undefined
```

There are many business process intensive method in those classes and i need the user defined logic to call and return rather than re-write from scratch.

Comment: Is the logic in the AliciaService and you has provide it?

Comment: sorry @ThorstenRintelen could you explain a bit? i not quite understand. basically if i call this this.alicia.dump(); right AFTER "... Function(...)..." it will work. But if the same function put inside user defined logic (which input from frontend), i will hit the error mentioned.

Comment: Can you share a plunker or so?

Comment: how bout stackbilitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fn-method-xa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution context of function that was created through `Function` constructor is a global object: `window` in your case.

In order to change this context you specify with each context to execute your function through `Function.prototype.call()`:

```
Function('...').call(this)
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fn-method-xa-p8tvrg)**

Comment: quick one, how could i push in 'moment' package? i updated the stackblitz project but it failed

Comment: Quick answer `Function('moment', '"use strict"; let inObj =' + JSON.stringify(inObj) + ';' + sUserDefinedCmd).call(this, moment)` https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fn-method-xa-pwgood

Comment: omg... i have to admit i can never guess the answer without your helps!! you saved my day!